# how to change price as correspondence changes occur in qty using jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have a table having qty and price, A user can change the qty manually by entering any number  OR he can also change the same by pressing + and - button. So I want, subtotal price should be change accordingly without reloading the page as its qty getting change. I dont want to store it in db and that unit price in picture is actually subtotal price which I need to change.

Here is a screen shot for clearly understanding my need:
[image]

Already I have spent lot of hours but I could not complete it so please some help me !

Comment: you want to store in DB also immediately after user enters value ?

Comment: You are using `Unit Price`, Why should it change? Secondly You need to share HTML and jQuery not a snap of site. Code Matter to us

Comment: do u want to change total price?

Answer (score 0):

Use following,Should i explain?

```
 $( "#qtyVal1" ).keypress(function(){
     var qty=$("#qtyVal1").val();
     var oldPrice=$("#priceDiv1").html();
     var total=qty*oldPrice;
     $("#priceDiv1").html("$"+total);
});
```

//If user presses +,- button

```
    $( "#qtyVal1" ).change(function(){
     var qty=$("#qtyVal1").val();
     var oldPrice=$("#priceDiv1").html();
     var total=qty*oldPrice;
     $("#priceDiv1").html("$"+total);
});
```